# Google docs for Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, google, google-drive

I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I want to install google docs or microsoft docs for offline use and when I connect with internet the all documents will update with server.

If it is possible , please suggest me how can I do it. If it is not possible please suggest me other options which is working on same concept.

Comment: Both tools you mention are for online use only.

Comment: Can you suggest me any one which works online and offline both

Comment: Any office suite does that.

Comment: @CelticWarrior sorry, but that information is wrong. Google Docs can handle documents offline.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily possible for google-docs. Just install the [chrome-browser](https://www.google.de/chrome/browser), or preferably the free [chromium-browser](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium) from the repositories and install the [Google-Docs plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake) from the web-store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i can access it only if I am connected with internet. I want to try the solution which will work online as well as offline. I mention it in my first line.

Comment: Yes, the plugin will work offline as well.